# ps command linux vs unix different behavior in c program

Tags: c, linux, unix

I have a simple c program that executes 'ps' and pipes it to 'grep', basically 'ps | grep x'.

the code goes more or less something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    int pid;

    pipe(pipefd);
    pid=fork();

    if (pid == 0){
        close(pipefd[1]);
        dup2(pipefd[0], 0);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "b", (char *) 0);
    }
    else{
        close(pipefd[0]);
        dup2(pipefd[1], 1);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execlp("ps", "ps", (char *) 0);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

The problem that i have is that when i run this on unix (Solaris) is works perfect, but when i run this on (Debian) it executes properly but gives me an error message.

error message:

```
Signal 17 (CHLD) caught by ps (procps-ng version 3.3.3).
ps:display.c:59: please report this bug
```

I have try the same program running different commands like 'ls' and 'grep' with no problem on either os. What makes 'ps' different?

**EDIT:** 
added the included libraries to the code.

Comment: Try reading about `SIGCHLD`.

Comment: thanks, that was actually helpful. I was googling 'signal 17' but was not getting any helpful information. it is late now, i will spend some time researching it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your program calls fork, it creates a parent process and a child process.  In the child process fork returns 0 and in the parent it returns 1.  Whenever a child process terminates, a SIGCHLD signal is sent to the parent process.

Now, in your case you call `execlp` in both the parent and child process, which replaces the running process image but does not change the relationship.  This means that `ps` is your parent process and `grep` is your child process.  Normally this would not matter, as programs ignore SIGCHLD by default, but `ps` catches all unknown signals and quits with the message you see there.  You can see the relevant function in the [source code for `ps`](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/ps/display.c?revision=1.32&view=markup) (or rather `procps`).

Comment: Yes, but is this happening because grep is abnormally terminating early, or as a result of a normal termination of grep at the end of input, and a race condition of ps not having terminated even though it has closed stdout?

Comment: I believe it's the second, but I'd need to stay up later than I'm willing to be sure :)

Comment: It is a somewhat atypical case - typically, if a shell set something like this up, the shell would be parent to both, instead of becoming one of the executed programs.  So having the original process fork twice and then wait on one of the children might be a solution.

Comment: That should certainly work.  To be honest, I don't think `ps` should be catching SIGCHLD at all, but that's not very helpful.  A simpler quick-fix might be to invert the `ps` and `grep` relationship, as grep will almost certainly ignore SIGCHLD.